# C - Typing a sentence in terminal

Tags: c

So I got this method where I have a char pointer in the parameter. `changeName(int id, char* data)`. I want to type in the data after I have typed in the id from the terminal. I've tried with scanf and gets but nothing is working.

edit: This is what I've already tried.

```
printf("Type in ID\n");
int command;
scanf("%d", &command);
printf("Type new name\n");
char* command = malloc(sizeof(char)*253);
scanf("%[^\n]%*c\n", data);
printf("%s\n", data);
change_name(command, data);
```

and I've tried with: `scanf("%s\n", data);`

Comment: Show us what have you already tried.

Comment: edited the post @Gasper

Comment: I think you want some variation of `scanf("%s"...)`, not `%c`. *(`%s` is for strings. `%c` is for a character)*

Comment: Sentence as in several words? Know that scanning %s stops at the first white-space. Did you consider using `fgets()` instead?

Comment: like fgets("%s", data) ? @Jens

Comment: No, it would be `fgets(data, 253, stdin);` assuming data was malloced the same. The manual page (`man fgets` on Unix) has the details.

Comment: `char* data = malloc(253);
scanf(" %252[^\n]%*c", data);`

Comment: remove `\n` from your scanf strings, it doesn't do what you think it does

Comment: `scanf("%[^\n]%*c", data);` leaves the newline in the buffer if the input only consists of newline, you need to use 2 separate calls to flush the newline

Answer (score 0):

1. `char* command = malloc(sizeof(char)*253);` : `command` typo as `data`. `sizeof(char)` always `1`.
2. Change `scanf("%[^\n]%*c\n", data);` to `scanf(" %252[^\n]%*c", data);`
   space of front of `%` for skip previous newline at `scanf("%d", &command);`
   Remove last `\n`of format. Because This waits for input.
   `252` is providing the limit in order to prevent the buffer overrun.

Answer (score 0):

User enters the id, plus a newline character.
The first call to scanf then eats the id, but not the newline. So on the next call, the newline is waiting and is immediately read. Solve that problem by adding whitespace after the %d.

Other problems are redefinition of command, and a bad second call to scanf. To read a line, just use fgets().